# Applying validation on condition using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Good morning guys, I wonder if you may help me on this issue: I'm applying a validation to a select element as required when another input value meets a condition. I'm using the validation jQuery plugin in order to do it. This is the pseudo-code: `if(textbox == "valueX"){mySelectEelement is required;}` (means that I must choose one value from the select element.). So for some reason the select element is not taking the validation I want to apply.

Please take a look on the full sample code I created for this purpose at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nKfSdNbdnTiz5iZ6KsfF?p=preview):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
$.validator.setDefaults({
      //debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });

    $( "#myform" ).validate({
      rules: {
        borough: {
              required: false
        }
      }
    });

    $('#state').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val().toUpperCase() == "NY" || $(this).val().toUpperCase() == "NEW YORK") {
        $('#borough').rules('add', {
            required: true
        });
    } else{
       $('#borough').rules('remove');
    }
});    
} );
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<div>
<p id="pid"></p>
<input id='text' type='text' value='other'/>
</div>
<br/>
 <input type="text" id="state" name="state"  />

  <select name="borough" id="borough">
  <option value="" select="selected"></option>
  <option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</option>
  <option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
  <option value="Queens">Queens</option>
  <option value="NY">NY</option>
  </select>
 </form></body> </html>
```

Comment: Please include ***all relevant*** code within the OP itself.  You also never explained the problem with your code or asked a question.  Thanks.

Comment: I just added the full sample.

Comment: The explanation is totally clear, I said I was trying that so if I say I need help in order to perform that task and expose the code is because it's not working well!

Comment: Thanks.  Obviously your question was clear to me as I answered it.  However, it was not written very well for SO's format.   Please review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more insight about my first comment.  This article might even be better for explaining:  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Thank you again @Sparky, I think the statement was good like that and don't needed to apply all those tutorial rules, I prefer keep simple. The important thing is that you understood and gave an accurate answer. However is good to know some new rules for the future.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also keep in mind that SO is more about helping future readers than any one individual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for external handlers and functions.  You would use the `depends` property under `required` within the `rules` object to contain your conditional logic...

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        borough: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    if ($('#state').val().toUpperCase() == "NY" || $('#state').val().toUpperCase() == "NEW YORK") {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/ubkb0pmd/](http://jsfiddle.net/ubkb0pmd/)**

---

And it works just as well without `depends`....

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        borough: {
            required: function(element) {
                if ($('#state').val().toUpperCase() == "NY" || $('#state').val().toUpperCase() == "NEW YORK") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/ubkb0pmd/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ubkb0pmd/1/)**

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was missing, the depends object. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I just tested it like this and it works too, I see my issue is that I was creating the rules in a separate statement (function) as all other lines are pretty much the same!

Comment: @John, actually, [your original method should have worked too](http://jsfiddle.net/ubkb0pmd/2/), although not as efficiently. Your root problem was that you declared `borough` as `required: true` right from the start, which takes precedence long before the user types anything into `state`.